# Permission class in Django

Tags: python, django

I use Django group permissions, I can assign some permission for users.
Here is my test scenario:

I have a Company Model,

**User1.hasPerm** -> `view_company, change_company, add_company, delete_company`

Permissions.py:

```
class HasPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    if request.user.has_perm('MYAPP.view_company'):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    if request.user.has_perm('MYAPP.change_company'):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    if request.user.has_perm('MYAPP.add_company'):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    if request.user.has_perm('MYAPP.delete_company'):
        return True
    else:
        return False

    return True
```

CompanyView.py:

```
class CompanyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
queryset = Company.objects.all()
filter_class = CompanyFilter
serializer_class = CompanySerializer
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, HasPermissions]

def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated and self.request.user.is_active:
        company = Company.objects.filter(companyUser__exact=self.request.user)
        return company
    else:
        return Company.objects.all()
```

I wrote `HasPermissions` function to control user permissions, and this function works only CompanyView. I want to make global this function for I can control all view.

`HasPermissions` function is like hard coding, I want to change the more usable version to control all views.

How can ı do this?

Comment: It likely does not work either, since you immediately return `False`. So after the first `else`, the rest is dead code.

Comment: yes, you're right how can ı more usable this function?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to write this yourself. Django already has a [**`DjangoModelPermissions`** [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions) for that:

> This permission class ties into Django's standard django.contrib.auth
>   model permissions. This permission must only be applied to views that
>   have a `.queryset` property set. Authorization will only be granted if
>   the user is authenticated and has the relevant model permissions
>   assigned.
>
> - POST requests require the user to have the `add` permission on the
>     model.
> - PUT and PATCH requests require the user to have the `change` permission on the model.
> - DELETE requests require the user to have the `delete` permission on the model.

So you can use:

```
class CompanyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    filter_class = CompanyFilter
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, DjangoModelPermissions]
```

Comment: I use your way but when ı delete the MYAPP.view_company permission from admin panel, the user still can access the company list?

Comment: @oerbas: did you remove the permission from the *user*?

Comment: @oerbas: exactly what is the logic here? That a user should have *any* of the permissions? or *all* of the permissions?

Comment: if user only has MYAPP.view_company then the user only lists the company. if the user only has 'MYAPP.view_company',
            'MYAPP.add_company' then the user only lists and add a company. Am ı clear?

Comment: @oerbas: you did link the permissions to the models right? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions

Comment: @oerbas: exactly what happens? What permissions did you give the user? Did you use that user for the API request? Is it too restrictive/too open?